# How to use Jackson to deserialise Array Like This?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

How to deserialise simple? My JSON look like:

```
{
"ok": 1,
"data": {
    "A": [
        {
            "brand": "Aman",
            "logo": "http://zxmall.bluedoor.com.cn/uploads/logo/61.png"
        }
    ],
    "B": [
        {
            "brand": "Base-DS",
            "logo": "http://zxmall.bluedoor.com.cn/uploads/logo/24.png"
        },
        {
            "brand": "BB",
            "logo": "http://zxmall.bluedoor.com.cn/uploads/logo/46.png"
        },
        {
            "brand": "Banane",
            "logo": "http://zxmall.bluedoor.com.cn/uploads/logo/11.png"
        }

    ],
    "C": [
        {
            "brand": "cat",
            "logo": "http://zxmall.bluedoor.com.cn/uploads/logo/78.png"
        },
        {
            "brand": "car",
            "logo": "http://zxmall.bluedoor.com.cn/uploads/logo/129.png"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

from [A-Z].

My code like below:

```
ReslutMod data = JsonUtil.jsonToMod(json, ReslutMod.class);
```

in JsonUtil:

```
public static  <T> T jsonToMod(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(jsonString)) {
         return null;
    }
    try {
        return JsonMapper
                .getInstance()
                .getJsonMapper().readValue(jsonString, clazz);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

JavaBean:

```
 public class ReslutMod {
    public int ok;
    public BrandListMod data;
 }
```

JavaBean2:

```
 public class BrandListMod {
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> A;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> B;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> C;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> D;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> E;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> F;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> G;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> H;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> I;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> J;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> K;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> L;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> M;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> N;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> O;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> P;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> Q;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> R;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> S;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> T;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> U;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> V;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> W;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> X;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> Y;
    public ArrayList<CardBrandModel> Z;
}
```

I don't think is a good way. What can I do?

Comment: can you make your question more clearer?you have already got one vote for close,if it reached 5 then your post will be closed.

Comment: If I am not wrong, here you wants to make your implementation more clean by reducing bean size.

Comment: If you want to optimize memory, you should use Stream Parser API of Jackson and create only one arraylist which contains all data from A to Z.

Comment: Yes,I just want to  create only one arraylist which contains all data from A to Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Map here.

E. g. :

```
class ReslutMod {
    public int ok;
    public Map<String, ArrayList<CardBrandModel>> data;

    public int getOk() {
        return ok;
    }

    public void setOk(int ok) {
        this.ok = ok;
    }

    public Map<String, ArrayList<CardBrandModel>> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Map<String, ArrayList<CardBrandModel>> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Where class CardBrandModel  will be like this :

```
class CardBrandModel {

    String brand;

    String logo;

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setLogo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

}
```